# Ionic 2/ angular 2 : string replaced with HTML tag isn't rendered properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of contents in my `JSON` which contain `URLs` in there as text. I want to find and replace those text `URLs` with links. What's actually happening? It does replace the URL with `<a>` tag and proper URL in `href=""` but still render this `<a>` tag as text and not as HTML

```
urlifyContent(){
   let urlRegex =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
   for (let index = 0; index < this.message.Content.length; ++index){
       this.message.Content[index] = this.message.Content[index].replace(urlRegex,`"<a href='$1'target='_blank'>$1</a>"`);
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you try to 'render' it? Are you placing it in a `{{var}}` inside an angular template?

Comment: {{message.Content}} it just put a changed URL with <a> tag as a text and not converting it into HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment you are using `{{message.Content}}` to bind the html you created using your `urlifyContent()` method. This will not work, because `{{}}` will parse the value to a string, and not HTML.

To add HTML to your page, you should use the `[innerHTML]` directive:

```
<div [innerHTML]="message.Content"></div>
```

However, it's worth mentioning that this won't parse any angular components or directives or binding present in that `HTML` snippet. It should just be plain html